# Community stopped locking questions when they are deleted as spam and no message saying the post is spam shown

Tags: discussion, spam, spam-detection

The two recent spam questions weren't locked upon deletion; moreover the spam text is not hidden as it is usually:

> [image]
>
> [image]

The default look when the spam is nuked properly:

> [image]

Also, looks like the last spam had the last spam flag from moderator, don't know about the first. Is it the reason?

Comment: Hmm, that happened before ...

Comment: One difference is the number of flags on them, assuming the number of downvotes reflect number of flags. And that is also true for the posts from Oded that Bart pointed out in chat.

Comment: Ah, maybe the whole user got nuked before the post itself was handled?

Comment: @Bart that is probably it. [Here is the latest evidence](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fsJHL.png)

Comment: So the @Oded retag clearly suggests this is not a bug???  Kind of surprising if you ask me.  The whole reason spam is locked and obfuscated is to prevent people from seeing the spam.  So why does a mod destroying a user as a purveyor of spam not do the same?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Diamond moderator (which is actually SE dev/employee here in MSE) nuked the account, choosing the "Destroy" option which automatically deletes all  posts with negative score of that user.

That's why the question wasn't locked or marked as spam.

Also, score of -4 proves that it accumulated maximum 4 spam flags.

That said, if the diamond user would directly flag a post as spam, it would cause automatic lock, deletion, and the message to appear, but won't nuke the account.

Comment: Then why deleted by community? Why not say deleted by "mod who deleted user" right?

Comment: "Just"? It was already nuked when I posted my question. Ok, I got why it wasn't locked.

Comment: @UniKitty because it was deleted by the automatic process triggered by destroying the account. Same as when OP close own question as dupe with the new "I agree" button.

Comment: score shows only how many users with downvote privileges voted (>=125 rep). If I understand correctly, users under 125 can cast spam flags too, but they can't downvote

Comment: @gnat wrong. spam/offensive flag also cause automatic downvote. (cast by Community user, who has a diamond thus can downvote even though has only 1 rep)

Comment: Another question there is the Community user is a hacker. It's downvoting one post multiple times!

Comment: @nicael good point! Guess that it's the only user capable of doing it, even developers can't vote more than once (as far as I know) unless going directly to database

Comment: @nicael You too can downvote multiple times - first downvote normally (-1) then flag as spam (-2) ;)

Comment: @David the point was it's not me downvoting the second time but Community user. Also, using a offensive/spam flags just to downvote is... abusive.

Comment: @nicael Not if it's spam ... ;)

Comment: @David certainly :D